# What does "casual and bold" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Ran into this:

> For the hundredth time he resented the element of imprecision, the margin of guesswork that entered into the business. The project as he had worked it out was **casual and bold**, the risks were considerable. Something might go wrong anywhere along the line. And therein lay the cunning of his scheme. No one would ever see in it the cautious, painstaking hand of Erwin Martin, head of the filing department at F & S, of whom Mr. Fitweiler had once said, "Man is fallible but Martin isn't." No one would see his hand, that is, unless it were caught in the act.

For context: [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http://jameshilston.com/pages/reading/catbird_seat.htm&ei=9CP9Ur-YDsiFogSGwYHAAQ&usg=AFQjCNF0BPhEl-n-I8N5KG-J8Fdlxg1fPA&sig2=szB1M7fwuUpcCWkwLMcUEQ)

1)What does **casual and bold** mean? is this an idiom?

2)If you were to say the above two sentences with simpler words, how would you do that?

Comment: The collocation is not an idiom: the two words have their ordinary independent meanings, which you can find in a dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Superficially, the two words don't seem to fit well together. In some ways, they're almost *opposites*:-

> 1a: [casual](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/casual) *- **seeming** or tending to be indifferent to what is happening; apathetic; unconcerned*
>    1b: [bold](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bold?s=t) *- necessitating courage and daring; challenging*

But as so often happens with English, there's a spread of meanings for each word:-

> 2a: [casual](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/casual) *- unpremeditated; offhand*
>    2b: [bold](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bold) *- not hesitating or fearful in the face of danger*

A useful word in this context that fits well with both the #2 definitions is

> 3: [**heedless**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/heedless?s=t) *- careless; thoughtless; unmindful [of danger]*

---

> *The project as he had worked it out was **heedless of considerable risks***.

But I'd have to say that the original is much better (James Thurber is after all a competent and justly respected writer). As he says only a couple of sentences later, *"No one would ever see in it [the project] the cautious, painstaking hand of Erwin Martin ["he", who actually worked out the plan]*.

The plan is *intended* to appear "casual" so others won't guess who's behind it (Martin has a reputation for being *cautious* rather than *bold*, *painstaking* rather than *casual*). That's why I highlighted the word *seeming* above (note how often the collocation [**studied** casualness](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22studied%20casualness%22) occurs in Google Books).

The long and short of it is - if you find Thurber's (careful) use of language confusing, you should probably swap to simpler texts for a while. It's literature aimed at competent native speakers who are comfortable with constructions that may be less common today, not sample text for learning English.

Answer (score 1):

The usage

> "*casual and bold*"

can be taken to mean "*[ **both** ] casual and bold*".

This allows interpretations where the the words are not providing copies of the same meaning, but are each meaning different things.

e.g. you can read it as meaning "*both unpremeditated and daring*".

Which is, in fact the reading I gave it.